# Solving linear equations, with 3 unknowns and an arbitrary constant

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I was asked to find a system of linear equations with the 3 unknowns, namely, $x$, $y$ and $z$ and their solutions are:
$$x= 6+5t,\quad y=4+3t,\quad z=2+t.$$

I have gotten this far : $t=z-2$
and i have substituted the values for $t$ into both the equations $x$ and $y$:
$x= 5z-4$, $y= 3z-2$.

I am stuck at this point, and I do not know how to continue further.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The equations you have provided parametrize a line in three dimensional space (where $t$ corresponds to the location on that line). It is not possible to "solve" this system, unless I am misunderstanding what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is asking you to convert from one representation of a line to another. Projective geometry provides an easy way to solve such problems.

The given parametric equations describe a line. From the equations, we can read that this line is the join of the points $\mathbf p=[6:4:2:1]$ and $\mathbf q=[5:3:1:0]$, i.e., all linear combinations $\lambda\mathbf p+\mu\mathbf q$, which can be expressed in matrix form as $$P\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}6&5\\4&3\\2&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda\\\mu\end{bmatrix}.$$

The line can also be viewed as the common intersection of a pencil of planes. For any such plane $\mathbf\pi$, the points $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$ lie on the plane, i.e., $\mathbf\pi^T\mathbf p=\mathbf\pi^T\mathbf q=0$, i.e., these planes are in the null space of $P^T$. Using any of the usual methods of finding a basis for this space, we can find that it’s spanned by $[3:-5:0:2]$ and $[1:-2:1:0]$, so a system of equations that has this line as a solution is $$3x-5y-2=0\\x-2y+z=0.$$

---

You can use the same ideas without bringing projective geometry into the picture. You’re starting with the representation of a line as a point and direction vector: $(6,4,2)^T+t\,(5,3,1)^T$. A line can also be represented as the intersection of two planes, and a single linear equation represents a plane, so this line requires a system of two linear equations. There are an infinite number of such planes to choose from, of course, but we know that they will all be parallel to the direction vector of the line, $(5,3,1)^T$. So, pick two linearly independent vectors that are perpendicular to this one. These vectors will respectively lie in each of the two planes being constructed. An easy choice is $(-1,0,5)^T$ and $(0,-1,4)^T$. The normals to the two planes are then $(-1,0,5)^T\times(5,3,1)^T=(15,-26,3)^T$ and $(0,-1,4)^T\times(5,3,1)^T=(13,-20,-5)^T$ and, using the point-normal form of equation for a plane, the two equations are $$(15,-26,3)^T\cdot(x,y,z)=(15,-26,3)^T\cdot(6,4,2)^T \\ (13,-20,-5)^T\cdot(x,y,z)=(13,-20,-5)^T\cdot(6,4,2)^T$$ which expands to $$15x-26y+3z+8=0\\13x-20y-5z+12=0.$$ You can verify that the original line satisfies this system by plugging in the values of the coordinates from the parametric equations.

Answer (score 0):

The system is already "solved". You have $x, y, z$ each in terms of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(x,y,z)=(6+5t,4+3t,z=2+t)$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$, is the parametric representation of a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So there are infinite solutions: for any given $t$, you obtain a unique triple $(x,y,z)$.